# How to create a hyperlink text in Word with a blue prism?

Tags: vba, ms-word, blueprism

I need to change text to hyperlink text in MS Word with a blue prism. I get it working with the code below, but it creates the wrong full path `C:\Users\me199ur\Desktop\testfolder\www.test.com`

I just need `www.test.com`

And without the Anchor or not object Anchor (e.g. String) it throws the error
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add

```
Dim document As Object = GetDocument(handle,document_name)

Dim range As Object = document.Range
Dim i As Integer 

range.Find.Forward = True

Do While range.Find.Execute(current_text)

    If True Then
        range.Text = new_text
        range.Bold = new_bold
        range.Hyperlinks.Add (range, "www.test.com")
    End If
    i = range.End
    range.Start = i
Loop
```

Comment: Add `http://` to your hyperlink as in `http://www.test.com`.

Comment: With "http://" It is already working. OMG I cannot beleave this caused the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Arul consider adding your comment as an answer, so that it might help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `http://` to your hyperlink as in `http://www.test.com`, when you need to hyperlink a website. Without `http://` or the protocol, any text is considered as an anchor or bookmark within your document.